# JsTree not picking up javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

[image]

Hi I am not yet fluent with javascript coming from a C# background. I am using Jstree im my MVC project and I can display the tree populated with Json data.

However I cannot add any plugins etc, Jstree doesn't seem to be picking up my Javascript file.

In my Index.cshtml I have.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jsTree/themes/default/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jsTree3/jstree.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/index.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my index.js I have

```
$(function () {
    $("#jstree").jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : { 
                'url ': "/SinqLaison/GetJsTree3Data",
                'dataType' : "json" 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any changes I make in the index.js file have no effect on the tree. Even if I remove the index.js file completely the tree displays the data like I'ts not picking up the index.js file at all.

Am I using jstree correclty? Should all the javascript I write be written in the jstree.js file the comes in when importing Jstree? and not in a custom index.js

many thanks.

Comment: what is there in the `index.js`?  why is it supposed to affect the tree?

Comment: Hi Nikolay thanks for replying the only code that is in hte index.js file is the code '$(function () {
$("#jstree").jstree({
    'core': { 'data': { 'url': "/SinqLaison/GetJsTree3Data", 'dataType': "json" } }
});});' i take that I am meant to work with the jstree.js file only?

Comment: so far in the `index.js` you just load the tree and that's it. if you want to see anything happen if you click a node, you will need to attach that to events fired on tree - in this case it would be `select_node.jstree` event

Comment: The thing is tho that if I comment out all the code in the index file, the tree still displays like the index.js file is not conenct to the tree in any way.

Comment: It means you initialize it somewhere else.  The library doesn't turn a div into a tree by itself. Did you change the original `jstree.js` file?

Comment: Thanks Nikolay I did mae a few edits to see if anything would change, so I take it that initalization is done somewhere in the Jstree.js file, I'll load the demo into a sperate project and see if i can track down where that is done. Non of the tutorials I looked at showed how this is done they just added code to seperate .js file like the index.js file I have.

Comment: Well, my point was that the original `jstree.js` doesn't do anything, until you call `.jstree(...)` on an element. So if you see it there, someone is calling it. So separating this into a stand-alone project would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks again, yes I will try in seperate project and see if i can work out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

There must have been a glitch when importing the Nuget Package, I uninstalled the JsTree then reinstalled it and it now works great.